# For what values of the alignment parameter does std::align work as expected?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I want to use `std::align` to align a buffer of `unsigned char` to a specific power-of-two value.

So far the [documentation that I looked at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align) seems to say this should work, except for this critical caveat at the end of the description:

> The behavior is undefined if alignment is not a fundamental or
>   extended alignment value supported by the implementation (until C++17)
>   power of two (since C++17).

I can't fully parse that. If I had to take a guess, the last part means "until C++17, `alignment` needs to be a *fundamental or extended alignment* and after C++17, it just needs to be a power of two".

Is my parsing correct?

More importantly, I'm interested in the C++11 behavior: what are the definitions of *fundamental* and *extended* alignment and how can I determine what my implementation supports?

Finally, what happens if I pass a value of `alignment` that does satisfy the above - is it UB or just an implementation-defined result?

Perhaps I could determine the answers myself with access to the standard, but based on my search it seems to be a pay-to-read document.

Comment: It reads as In pre C++17 *The behavior is undefined if alignment is not a fundamental or extended alignment value supported by the implementation* and in C++17 *The behavior is undefined if alignment is not a power of two*

Comment: What are _fundamental or extended alignments_?

Comment: Not 100% certain but I would assume *fundamental* means built in type size and *extended* is anything after that the implementation wants to support

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.align#:alignment,fundamental

Comment: Thanks @jbapple - what version of C++ is that document for? It provides some very relevant info but mentions things like `_­_­STDCPP_­DEFAULT_­NEW_­ALIGNMENT_­_­` which seem to be new for `c++17`.