# Can I use std::align to align memory to arbitrary values of 2?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I am having a hard time interpreting the following description of `std::align` from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align

```
void* std::align(std::size_t alignment,
                 std::size_t size,
                 void*& ptr,
                 std::size_t& space );
```

> The behavior is undefined if alignment is not a fundamental or extended alignment value supported by the implementation (until C++17) power of two (since C++17).

If my understanding is correct then this means that for C++11 using `std::align` is undefined behavior if your requested alignment does not match the alignment of one of the C++ builtin types like `short, int, long, double, ...`. Hence using `std::align` with an alignment value greater than `std::max_align_t` (which is usually 8 or 16) causes undefined behavior.

But now for C++17 there has been a change:

> ... power of two (since C++17).

I guess this means that since C++17 any power of 2 value is a valid alignment for `std::align`.

Can anybody confirm this?

### Update:

For both GCC's and LLVM's `std::align` implementations any power of 2 value is a valid alignment. For any non power of 2 alignment value GCC's and LLVM's `std::align` implementations cause undefined behavior.

- GCC's `std::align` [implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/41d6b10e96a1de98e90a7c0378437c3255814b16/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/memory#L114)
- LLVM's `std::align` [implementation](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/6952d1478ddd5a1870079d01f1a0e1eea5b09a1a/src/memory.cpp#L217)

This seems to confirm my assumption:

> since C++17 any power of 2 value is a valid alignment for std::align.

And I have tested that even for C++11 `std::align` works correctly for any power of 2 alignment value using GCC, LLVM and MSVC.

Comment: already asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232984/for-what-values-of-the-alignment-parameter-does-stdalign-work-as-expected, but no answer aside from a few comments ...

Comment: OK, thanks. I will try to find LLVM's and GCC's implementations of std::align and see how they interpret the standard...

Comment: For GCC any alignment value is OK: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/41d6b10e96a1de98e90a7c0378437c3255814b16/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/memory#L114

Comment: LLVM's implementation works with any power of 2 value and causes undefined behavior for any non power of 2 value: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/6952d1478ddd5a1870079d01f1a0e1eea5b09a1a/src/memory.cpp#L217

Comment: Actually GCC's implementation also causes undefined behavior for any non power of 2 value.

Answer (score 1):

> for C++11 using std::align is undefined behavior if your requested alignment does not match the alignment of one of the C++ builtin types like short, int, long, double, ....

That's not what cppreference or [the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/ptr.align) says. From C++14 [ptr.align]/2.1:

> **alignment** shall be a fundamental alignment value or an extended alignment value supported by the implementation in this context

A fundamental alignment is not the alignment of a fundamental type. From [[basic.align]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.align#2):

> A fundamental alignment is represented by an alignment less than or equal to the greatest alignment supported by the implementation in all contexts, which is equal to `alignof(std::max_align_t)` (18.2).

So it's just that. Coupled with [basic.align]/4's statement that all alignments must be powers-of-two, that means that a fundamental alignment is any alignment less than or equal to `alignof(std::max_align_t)`.

Comment: What about C++17, can you confirm or deny that any power of 2 value is a valid alignment?

Comment: @Linoliumz: It's plain English text; it means what it says. I don't know why you need that verified.

Comment: For me it is confusing because I don't know if "power of two (since C++17)" is a standalone sentence or if it must somehow be combined with the first part of the sentence.

Comment: @Linoliumz: Cppreference is kind of like a diff. Version-specific content must be read/ignored based on what version you want to apply it to. If a piece of boxed text says "since C++17", and you want to know how something works in C++17, then that text applies to C++17 and beyond. If a piece of boxed text says "until C++17", then that text applies to all versions until C++17. If you're reading it for what C++17 says, then you *ignore* that box. Unversioned text applies to all versions (that are applicable. `std::align` is a C++11 function, so unboxed text implicitly requires C++11).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation :-)